# Cannot remove index.php using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

When I try to remove index.php
and access controller: mysite.com/admin
I keep getting Internal Server Error.
I have no idea why it doesn't work.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /code/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Site config

```
<Directory /home/mysite.com/public_html/>
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Apache error log

```
[Sat Sep 08 15:24:30 2012] [error] [client 176.106.162.240] 
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects 
due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' 
to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the server error log to see exactly what it says the problem is to cause that 500? You should do some basic debugging yourself, which always starts with looking at logs, rather than making us guess at the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /code/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Into this one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

I do not believe you need anything else.

Comment: hey , i have Index.php instead of index.php , can u help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at it in detail I see a problem with `RewriteBase /code/`

Try with `RewriteBase /`

Answer (score 0):

```
You just need to create .htaccess file in project folder and write:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   #ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

 #And You don't need to define in base_url in config file:

 $config['base_url'] = '';// blank it.

 I hope it will work perfectly ...
```